# How to set link on image using maplink in responsive theme?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a link on image through *maplink* but it is not working with responsive theme. I don't know how to make it responsive. If anybody have some idea plz share.

**html**

```
    <img src="http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/MyLuckyBottle/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/home_background.jpg" alt="new" width="100%" border="0" usemap="#Map2" />
<map name="Map2" id="Map2">
  <area shape="poly" coords="691,918,705,756,931,763,910,930,692,920" href="http://youtu.be/zG28Gy6mKO0" target="_self" alt="new-video" />
</map>

    </div>
```

**css**

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/gVu5y/

**HTML**

```
<div class="map">
    <img src="http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/MyLuckyBottle/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/home_background.jpg"/>
    <a href="#" class="a"></a>
    <a href="#" class="b"></a>
    <a href="#" class="c"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.map {
    position: relative;
}

div.map > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

div.map > a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

div.map > a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}

div.map > a.a {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

div.map > a.b {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
}

div.map > a.c {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks coma you did it for me, +1  :)

Comment: Great! Nice question btw.

Comment: Is there any way to make link without anchor tag..?

Comment: I got [the trick](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.6.1) to make map link with anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

if you want to implement responsive design don't use image maps, instead you can use background image and `<a>` tags `position:absolute` to `div` which has image maps. Use percentages for best view in responsive layout.

**HTML**

```
<div class="conatiner">
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.conatiner{
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
}
.conatiner a{
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:30%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LY3q2/)**

Comment: Using an img tag instead of a background-image helps by giving to the container the right height.

Answer (score 0):

If you use image maps and the image may vary in size, then a pure HTML/CSS solution is not possible!

You have to use some assistent techniques like Javascript.

There is a jQuery plugin which re-calculates the map coordinates according to the image size:
[**jQuery-rwdImageMaps**](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)

But also remember that image maps are hard to recognize on touch devices!
And they are a "nightmare" from the accessibilty point of view.

So the best would be to not use image maps in responsive design!

Comment: I have call this script in file but still link is moving another place.

Comment: Please read and follow the instructions of the plugin (e.g. set unitless width and height in your image tag and override it in your CSS). The plugin works fine, if you do it right.